# How to combine multiple audios and videos into a single file?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, media, flv, mkv

I have a bunch of audio and video files and their corresponding start time in a stream.

Like this diagram below:

[image: Diagram]

How can I combine this all into a single video file efficiently?

I've tried `ffmpeg` but it was too slow (I don't know if I used `ffmpeg` correctly or not)

This is my `ffmpeg` command example:

```sh
ffmpeg -i audio_0_3.mp3 -i audio_1_4.mp3 -i audio_2_5.mp3 -i audio_2_6.mp3 -i audio_2_7.mp3 -i audio_3_10.mp3 -i audio_3_8.mp3 -i audio_3_9.mp3 \
-filter_complex [0:a]adelay=0ms[s0];[1:a]adelay=36282ms[s1];[2:a]adelay=462385ms[s2];[3:a]adelay=686909ms[s3];[4:a]adelay=876931ms[s4];[5:a]adelay=1675187ms[s5];[6:a]adelay=1339944ms[s6];[7:a]adelay=1567946ms[s7];[s0][s1][s2][s3][s4][s5][s6][s7]amix=inputs=8[s8] \
-map [s8] out.mp4
```

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: @llogan I just added it to the question.

Comment: Instead of putting a delay on each audio stream and mixing them together you can just use the concat filter to place one after the other. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat
Or if they all use the same codec you can use this technique which will be much quicker as it doesn't need to re-encode the audio streams https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743602/ffmpeg-trim-and-concat-mp3-without-re-encoding